# UDF Not found in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, user-defined-functions

I cannot wrap my head around on the select UDF statement referred from the link below:

[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (
  @InputString                  VARCHAR(500),
  @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(1)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
  Item                          VARCHAR(500)
)

AS
BEGIN
  IF @Delimiter = ' '
  BEGIN
        SET @Delimiter = ','
        SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
  END

  IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
        SET @Delimiter = ','

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

  DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(500)
  DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(500)
  DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

  SET @ItemList = @InputString
  SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

        -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
        SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
        SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  END -- End WHILE

  IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = @ItemList
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
  END

  -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
  ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

  RETURN

END -- End Function
GO
```

I checked the permission and also made sure that the function has been created in the correct schema using:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

However, I got into problem when I ran the following:

```
select dbo.Split(TargetFolderId, ',') from ReportConfig where ReportId = 9
```

**Error:**

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.Split", or the name is ambiguous.

but I can do

```
select * from dbo.Split('stringA,stringB', ',')
```

Could it be the difference between the SSMS version that both of us are using?

I am using SQL2017 - SSMS v17.4.

Comment: This is a table-valued function which returns result a TABLE. It has to be used as a table like "Select * from ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the function is defined as table-valued and you can't use it like that

```
select dbo.Split(TargetFolderId, ',') from ReportConfig where ReportId = 9
```

But you could perform `CROSS APPLY` to get `TargetFolderId` splitted values.

```
select sp.Item from ReportConfig rc
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(rc.TargetFolderId) AS sp
where rc.ReportId = 9
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer

```
RETURNS @Items TABLE (
  Item                          VARCHAR(500)
)
```

In your code your are returning to a table so you have to use function something like this

```
Select * FROM dbo.Split('1,2,3,4,5,6',',')
```

Result

```
Item
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: It is as mentioned, however, stormcloak gave an alternative to solve my problem, i will his as an answer. Nevertheless, thanks for your help!